# How to remove duplicates in a row that is separated by a space | Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just finished cleaning my data and I noticed that there are columns that have duplicate values in the rows that are separated by a space. I was wondering what is the best way to remove the space after the first value and then all values after it.

There are some columns that have multiple duplicates such as 42.35 42.25 23.12 in the same cell.

The data is large with 1500 columns and around 4000 rows so there is no way I could manually fix the issue.

Thanks!

Here is an example

```
    PAG
0   54.36
1   50.3
2   46.81
3   47.71
4   42.35 42.35          <------ This is one of the many rows (cell) that have this duplicate. 
5   43.91
6   43.54
```

Here is what the data looks like and the dtypes
Dtype

```
MthCalDt      int64
A           float64
AA          float64
AAL         float64
AAON        float64
             ...   
ZD          float64
ZEN         float64
ZION        float64
ZTS         float64
ZWS         float64
Length: 1583, dtype: object
```

```
cleaned_data = pd.read_csv("Wrds_Data\wrds_data_clean.csv")
cleaned_data.head()

    MthCalDt    A         AA    AAL     AAON    AAP     AAPL    AAT     AAWW    AB  ...     YUMC    YY         Z      ZBH     ZBRA    ZD    ZEN     ZION    ZTS     ZWS
0   20170131    48.97   36.45   44.25   33.95   164.24  121.35  42.93   52.75   23.35   ... 27.48   41.08   35.38   118.33  83.67   83.81   23.93   42.19   54.94   22.09
1   20170228    51.30   34.59   46.36   33.65   156.61  136.99  44.00   56.85   23.70   ... 26.59   44.29   33.94   117.08  90.71   81.42   27.23   44.90   53.31   22.17
2   20170331    52.87   34.40   42.30   35.35   148.26  143.66  41.84   55.45   22.85   ... 27.20   46.11   33.67   122.11  91.25   83.91   28.04   42.00   53.37   23.08
3   20170428    55.05   33.73   42.62   36.65   142.14  143.65  42.83   58.00   22.90   ... 34.12   48.97   39.00   119.65  94.27   90.24   28.75   40.03   56.11   24.40
4   20170531    60.34   32.94   48.41   36.18   133.63  152.76  39.05   48.70   22.55   ... 38.41   58.34   43.52   119.21  104.34  84.62   25.98   40.07   62.28   22.80
```

What I tried So Far Comes up with the error could not convert a string into float. The error is caused by the duplicate with a space in one of the rows (Cell)

```
cleaned_data = pd.read_csv("Wrds_Data\wrds_data_clean.csv")
cleaned_data.astype(float)
cleaned_data.applymap(lambda x: x.split(" ")[0])


error: 
could not convert string to float: '126.49 126.49'    <--- This is referencing a duplicate cell that is considered a string since there is a space.
```

Here is the newer code with regex that tries to replace cells with spaces but there are still cells with duplicates.

```
cleaned_data = pd.read_csv("Wrds_Data\wrds_data_clean.csv")
columns = cleaned_data.columns.copy().drop('MthCalDt')
cleaned_data[columns] = cleaned_data[columns].replace(r"^(\d+\.\d+) .*", r"\1", regex=True).astype(float)
cleaned_data



Error: 

Cell In [114], line 3
      1 cleaned_data = pd.read_csv("Wrds_Data\wrds_data_clean.csv")
      2 columns = cleaned_data.columns.copy().drop('MthCalDt')
----> 3 cleaned_data[columns] = cleaned_data[columns].replace(r"^(\d+\.\d+) .*", r"\1", regex=True).astype(float)
      4 cleaned_data


169     # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
--> 170     return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
    172 return arr.astype(dtype, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '60 55.66'
```

**Here is the Step By Step Guide for what I did when cleaning the data to show if I made a mistake when cleaning the data.**

Step 1. Showing what the original Data looked like.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("Wrds_Data\wrds_data_raw.csv")

output:
    Ticker  MthCalDt    MthPrc
0   JJSF    20170131    127.57
1   JJSF    20170228    133.8
2   JJSF    20170331    135.56
3   JJSF    20170428    134.58
4   JJSF    20170531    130.1
```

Step 2: Making the Tickers into columns and MthPrc as the Values indexed in MthCalDt

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("Wrds_Data\wrds_data_raw.csv")
df2 = df1.pivot_table(index='MthCalDt', columns="Ticker", values="MthPrc", aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna()))
df2.to_csv("Wrds_Data\wrds_data_clean.csv")
Output:
```

[image: Data Output]

Comment: What have you tried? Post your attempt here and the error it is producing.

Comment: What are the dtypes of these columns? `object`? Do you want them to be floats?

Comment: floats would be perfect. @tdelaney

Comment: Use `aggfunc='first'` instead of your `lambda`. That's where your duplicate values are coming from... or `mean`... or there are many other options. You have to decide what you want to happen there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace with a regex that looks for digits followed by a space.

```
df.replace(r"^(\d+\.\d+) .*", r"\1", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

You could also take the opportunity to change the values to floats while you are at it. In your example, you have many columns that should be floats and one that looks like it should stay like it is. So, just to keep life complicated, I'll drop the columns that should not be visited in the conversion.

```
columns = df.columns.copy().drop('MthCalDt')
df[columns] = df[columns].replace(r"^(\d+\.\d+) .*", r"\1", regex=True).astype(float)
```

Comment: I tried implementing your suggestion but some cells still have duplicates and therefore can't convert into a float. Ill put an updated error with the code above. @tdelaney

Comment: I haven't figured that one out. Can you take the existing data that is causing the problem and create a small sample dataframe with that field? Perhaps use `.to_csv('test.csv')` to make something that is easy to import?

Comment: I'll provide a step-by-step guide on what I did when cleaning the data to show if I created the problem in the first place. @tdelaney

Comment: @TrevorSeibert - I see a problem. `'60 55.66'` - I was assuming everything to convert was a float (had a . in it). Let me do some fiddling. Its not a duplicate. Do you want to keep the 60 or the 55.66?

Comment: @TrevorSeibert - You could potentially use `.replace(r"(\d+[^ ]*).*", r"\1", regex=True)` which will search to the first digit and then select everything up to the next space or end of file. That's the challenge of scrubbing, its a guess about the data and tweaks may be needed.

Answer (score 3):

- `applymap`: apply in every cell
- `x.split(" ")[0]`: choose the first value split by a space

```py
df.applymap(lambda x: float(str(x).split(" ")[0]))
```

Comment: I'm not certain that OP understands that you need `df = df.applymap(...` to make these changes stick.